# How to parse an object and covert it into an array

Tags: javascript, json

Hi i want to convert by object into an array i don't have any ideas how to do that.

Object

```
{ stops: [ 'Route1', 'Route2' ], time: [ '12:00 am', '12:30 am', '01:00 am', '01:30 am', '02:00 am' ], _id: 5c636357bc92ec0e44a44946}
```

how to parse `time: [ '12:00 am', '12:30 am', '01:00 am', '01:30 am', '02:00 am' ]`, like this one.

Array

```
[ '12:00 am', '12:30 am', '01:00 am', '01:30 am', '02:00 am' ]
```

Comment: its already an array.  I guess you mean to say how to access it? so if then `obj.time` will let you access your time object directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use . notation to access the time property

```js
var obj={ stops: [ 'Route1', 'Route2' ], time: [ '12:00 am', '12:30 am', '01:00 am', '01:30 am', '02:00 am' ], _id: '5c636357bc92ec0e44a44946'}
console.log(obj.time)
```

Comment: OP does not seem to have idea about this, just made it easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

for converting all things into an array

```
let obj={ stops: [ 'Route1', 'Route2' ], time: [ '12:00 am', '12:30 am', '01:00 am', '01:30 am', '02:00 am' ], _id: 5c636357bc92ec0e44a44946}

let arr=[...obj.stops,...obj.time,obj._id]
```

and simply if you want to convert only time attribute then

```
   let obj={ stops: [ 'Route1', 'Route2' ], time: [ '12:00 am', '12:30 am', '01:00 am', '01:30 am', '02:00 am' ], _id: 5c636357bc92ec0e44a44946}
    let arr=[...obj.time]
```